# PowerApps Custom Connector: How to POST binary data in request body?

Tags: post, binary, powerapps, power-apps-custom-connector

Using Postman to test an API, I'm able to select `Body/binary` then choose an image file stored locally. Postman inserts binary data somehow into the request and I get a favorable response:

[image]

[image]

When trying to build this as a Custom Connector in PowerApps, I can't find any info on what the schema for the `Body` of the request should be.

[image]

When I try to add a generic `{"body": ""}` body to the connector with a `string` type of `binary`, I receive this error:

```
Specified swagger has the following errors: 'Definition is not valid. Error: 'Error : paths/~1prebuilt~1analyze/post/parameters/2/schema/properties/body : A schema with type/format 'string/binary' can only be at the top level of a body or formData parameter. '
```

Comment: @carlosfigueira, do you have any insights on this one?

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same problem.

Body:

```
""
```

When you have clicked Import, go to the request -> body -> body and click the three dots -> Edit.

Under Body, it will say "key-body-output". Click the three dots and click Edit.
Change Type to **String** (if not already) and change Format to **Binary**. Change Is required to **Yes**.

Update the connector and you can now use the custom connector with PowerApps by using ImageX.Image for the body property for example.